# Solving for multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am not very complex math savvy. With that said, I am trying to help solve a complex problem related to benefit premium reconciliation at work and do not have the expertise to do so.

**Here is the scenario:**

1. Client has been sold a benefit that is billed per employee by age band. There are 12 age bands in total.
2. As the age of an employee increases, so does the rate.
3. Each employee selects his/her benefit amount (volume).
4. Client must report in summary, by age band, how many employees, their corresponding total volume, and the corresponding premium it has in each age band (premium = lives $\times$ (volume/1,000) $\times$ rate).
5. Company must input these values from the client into the billing system to reconcile the billed amount against what the client has submitted.

**Here is the issue:**

6. The client does not have the ability to extract the required details from its system by age band
7. The client, can, however provide a summary of total lives, total volume, and total premium calculated
8. Company must then calculate how many lives and volume are associated with each age band in order to reconcile exactly to the premium sent by the client.

**For Example:**

Rate for Age Band 1 = $0.01 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 2 = $0.02 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 3 = $0.03 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 4 = $0.04 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 5 = $0.05 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 6 = $0.06 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 7 = $0.07 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 8 = $0.08 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 9 = $0.09 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 10 = $0.10 (8 lives, 800,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 11 = $0.11 (10 lives, 1,000,000 volume)

Rate for Age Band 12 = $0.12 (10 lives, 1,000,000 volume)

Client Reported Lives = 100

Client Reported Volume = 10,000,000

Client Reported Premium = $6.70

Lives and volume are not known by company since client cannot provide them, but must be solved for based on what the company does know - rate per age band - and what client does know - summary of lives, volume, and premium.

***I have provided lives and volume by age band in order to help confirm results***

Any help developing an equation to do this is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have a question: Where is your attempt at this problem and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @JohnDouma I wish I could say that I attempted to solve this, but, honestly, I don't even know where to start. I basically need to solve for 24 different variables and it is was past my skillset.